# How do you use compositeData inside a REST control

Tags: xpages

I have a custom control with an ExtLib REST control on it. I'm creating JSON from the rest control. It's working fine if I hardcode everything inside the doGet tag.

But when I try and access the custom properties via compositeData in the do get I get an error:

```
com.ibm.domino.services.ServiceException: Error while rendering service

Caused by: com.ibm.xsp.exception.EvaluationExceptionEx: Error while executing JavaScript action expression
    at com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptMethodBinding.invoke(JavaScriptMethodBinding.java:126)
    at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.rest.CustomService$ScriptServiceEngine.renderServiceGet(CustomService.java:311)
    at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.rest.CustomService$ScriptServiceEngine.renderService(CustomService.java:262)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: com.ibm.jscript.InterpretException: Script interpreter error, line=11, col=14: [ReferenceError] 'compositeData' not found
```

Is there a way to use composite to create my JSON object?

I'm trying to create an object like this:

```
var object = {};
object.height = compositeData.height
return toJson(object)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The REST Control should be considered as an independent component that has no direct access to the page on which it exists because it is possible to call the REST service via a url similar to `database.nsf/page.xsp/RESTServiceName`.

what you should do instead is call your REST service with a url that includes parameters to pass into the control such as `database.nsf/page.xsp/RESTServiceName?height=20&width=50` and then reference them within the control using `param.get("height")` and `param.get("width")`.

Another option could be to put the parameters into a scope variable and read them from there.

Answer (score 0):

When the data is called from the Rest object it doesn't call the XPage in that moment, so the component tree isn't loaded. You could try using ${} instead of #{} when computing?